Torus Circle Meridian modification for Cassinian Intersections
Is it possible to define a torus whose sections parallel to torus axis are Ovals of Cassini?
For contextual reference sections of a Circular Torus and code (Mathematica) are given below:
We can see various intersection profiles that are similar to ellipses when outer intersection plane distance draws towards the torus axis gradually transitioning to two circles and then as hyperbolae alikes when inner torus radius is reached.

How is the circular section/meridian redefined in order that sectional profiles are Cassinian Ovals?
Thanks, hope it will be interesting to find the " Cassinian torus."
